# How should I reply when I answer some question on Stack Exchange sites, people thank me and say it helped?

Tags: phrase-usage

In order to be polite and answer in a social way I have had some hesitation to choose which phrase I should use.

1. You are welcome. I'm glad it helped.
2. You are welcome. I'm glad I could contribute.
3. You are welcome. I'm glad that I could help.
4. No problem. I'm happy that I could help.

If you have better phrases, please add, since it's fun to learn more.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57969/discussion-on-question-by-adam-how-should-i-reply-when-i-answer-some-question-on).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

All your examples are fine. I would offer the following advice to make it sound more natural to a native, however, the most important of which can be summarised by saying **keep it short**.

- Shorten "You are welcome" to **"You're welcome"**.
- You don't necessarily need to say **I'm** in the follow-up sentences, as this is obvious to the reader from context. Saying something like **"Happy to help"** or **"Glad it helped"** is fine. In fact, if you use the word "I" or "me" too much, it can come across as being self-congratulatory/boastful/self-centered/self-important.
- The simple acknowledgement of thanks is often sufficient ("You're welcome"), you don't necessarily also need to state your happiness for being helpful.
- (Flagrantly stealing from Robusto's comment) You can often shorten "you're welcome" or "no problem" to the acronyms **YW** or **NP**.
- Use exclamation marks or smiley faces to appear more jovial, e.g. **"Happy to help!"** or **"You're welcome :)"**.
- **Contribute** is probably more appropriate if it was a group effort, e.g. a discussion, otherwise, **help** is probably more appropriate. You can also use **"to be of service"** (e.g. "Glad to be of service"), but "help" is again probably more informal/generally appropriate.
- If you don't know whether the OP has found something helpful yet, you can use **"I hope"** to indicate that you would like your contribution to be helpful. You could say something like **"I hope you find it useful/helpful"**.
- (Especially if you are Australian/speaking to an Aussie) You can use the phrase **"No worries"** in a similar way to "No problem".

Comment: I'm not so sure about "YW" or "NP". I would have no idea what you're talking about. Better to just write it out in full.

Comment: as a Brit, "happy to help" sounds like an Americanism and often seems insincere, in the same way that people are *required* to say "have a nice day" as part of their job, not because they mean it.

Comment: While well written, this answer doesn't actually address the context - Stack Exchange. We don't do that here; see https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/127222/27657

Comment: @T.J.L. You're absolutely correct, and that's why the answer that has addressed it has got a higher score so far!

Comment: FWIW, as an AmE speaker, "No worries" sounds more like a way to respond to somebody apologizing for a minor inconvenience. Outside of an Australian context, I'd be concerned that "no worries" would imply to the other person that they inconvenienced me.

Comment: @FighterJet : I would question YW without context.  But if this was said in response to someone who just said "ty", I'd be much more likely to figure it out.

Comment: @TOOGAM: I'd probably figure it out eventually, but it might take a bit of thinking. Just like I have to think about what YMMV means if I haven't seen it in a while ("your mileage may vary"), or IMHO ("in my humble opinion"). Maybe it's just me, but I greatly dislike this tendency to initialise common language because it greatly reduces comprehension. I never got on the "gr8 ur awsum" bandwagon either.

Comment: @FighterJet As you accurately remark, that is common language. Consequently, no deep comprehension is required – using abbreviations would be apt.

Comment: @user: Abbreviations, sure. I have no problem with _OK_, _cause_, _int'l_, or _N. America_. Everybody can figure out what those mean. But initialisms like IANAL or IMHO are opaque and (unless you're on Twitter) are of little benefit.

Comment: @alephzero this is extremely useful feedback! I have frequently used the phrase "happy to help" to indicate that ... well, that I am happy to help. It's sad that my recipients may have thought it is insincere.

Answer (score 95):

I commend your desire to be polite!

However, since your question is specifically about “stackoverflow sites”, I recommend you do **not** respond to “thank you” comments or post your own “thank you”-type comments. [The “What should I do when someone answers my question?” section of the site's Help Center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) says this:

> **Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you".** Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this up. I was hoping someone would.

Comment: @J.R. Please do not use comments to say "Thank you" ;-) Joking aside, I just learned this rule existed. The More You Know 

Comment: Yes, this. My suggestion would be to up-vote whatever kind of post they used. That gives them the "warm fuzzy" back that you'd like to give.

Comment: @T.E.D.: A warm fuzzy back? No thanks, I already have one.

Comment: Yet, is a full answer on ELL a place to teach the users stackexchange rules? Doesn't that break the rules on answering in its own right? Chatrooms are also a part of SE sites and the OP might be responding to a thank you there? Just wandering...

Comment: I felt this was appropriate because the question was specifically about “stackoverflow sites” (those were the words from the question title, which has since been edited to instead say “Stack Exchange sites”), where we encourage a particular etiquette, and @SteveES had already posted a very good answer applicable to other (non-Stack Exchange) sites and general writing.

Comment: If the comment doesn't contain much other than 'Thanks', you may want to consider flagging it as 'too chatty'

Comment: A good answer to the context of the question — if it were posted on Meta. As for here, let us take it to concern the broader question of how to reply to a compliment or the like.

Comment: @Lucky I believe you mean, "Just wondering." I see that mix-up a lot when I wander the Interwebs.

Comment: @Darcinon Yes, homophones keep haunting me :-). I'd say thanks for pointing it out, but being polite seems to be a great transgression here...

Answer (score 7):

None of the above. Comments are not supposed to say thank you or anything in return.

> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> - Compliments which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, up-vote it and pay it forward;

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

---

Edit: Comments are not for extended discussion either.

Comment: You're correct, but in the context of ELL, the other answers are more fitting - the responses are not limited to SO. This is a good **comment** for the OP.

Comment: Right: Don't say "thank you" and don't reply if someone does say "thank you". Both of these should be flagged as "Too chatty" and will be summarily deleted by moderators

Comment: @Bohemian: What I do sometimes if I feel that a thank you is warranted (e.g. they went out of their way to accommodate my perhaps unreasonable request, such as provide something tangentially related to the answer) is say thank you, then come back a few days later after they've had a chance to see it and delete the comment. Both missions of sincere expression of thanks and reduced clutter are accomplished.

Comment: @FighterJet don't do that; that's not what comments are for. Comments are for clarification. If you *really* want to thank someone, award a bounty.

Comment: @Bohemian: Technically, by your definition, I should never have made the request then, but I don't see it as a problem. And what if the answer doesn't warrant an up-vote or a bounty? "something tangentially related to the request" usually means something like a link to a high-res version of an image used in the answer that I want for other reasons, even if the answer is not great. I don't see why you're complaining, because I delete them after a few days, and it's not like this happens very often.

Comment: @FighterJet if you're asking for "more", that's a kind of clarification. If it's outside the scope of the original question, you should ask a new question. Don't use comments to ask questions, thanks/you're-welcome or other "conversational" content, or extended discussion.

Comment: @Bohe: [Here](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4511/56599) is a specific example. I don't believe the picture is good for small sizes in the header so I didn't upvote it, but I thought the picture would make a great desktop background. So I asked for a larger version, he complied, and I said "Hey, thanks!", which I have now deleted. What's the problem?

Comment: @FighterJet please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258032/256196)

Comment: A good answer to the context of the question — if it were posted on Meta.  As for here, let us take it to concern the broader question of how to reply to a compliment or the like.

Comment: @FighterJet please note [the tooltip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272944/673852) which you get when you hover an _upvote_ button: "_This answer is useful_". So it's quite wrong to say thanks but not upvote a useful answer.

Comment: @Ruslan, the thanks wasn't for the answer, it was for them complying with my request to post a link to a hi-res version of the image. But this discussion is getting off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

Your responses #1, #3, and #4 are entirely appropriate since you're answering directly to an individual.

#2 might be more for a general or bigger audience/community.

Depending on what the original question was

> Glad I could help. Good luck!

may also be appropriate.

Comment: #2 works with an individual as well.

Answer (score 1):

When people thank me I usually say:

> You're welcome, glad it helped. By the way thanks are immaterial in the Stack Exchange sites, so you can vote on or accept my answer if you find it useful.

By saying so you also have the chance to get an upvote.